# GAE - JPA - datanucleus data retrieval error - PESSIMISTIC_READ

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I am App Engine 1.8.5 and its default nucleus data store version. I am working in local Eclipse Setup which has GAE plug-in .

It is successfully working in my local machine for all data store and retrieval. It deployed successfully in the Google App engine server. URLs which don't have data store relation are working fine without any issue.
The problem is with datastore retrieval in the server.  I am using JPA api for datastore using GAE datanuclues engine.

The issue is while I retrieve the data from datastore it is throwing PESSIMISTIC_READ error in server but not at local machine. I am stuck and not able to proceed.

I have pasted the stack trace , persistence.xml and EMF.java file for your reference. Pls help.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PESSIMISTIC_READ
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:171)
    at com.ideafolks.codelist.datastore.dao.SectorDAO.getAllSector(SectorDAO.java:122)
    at com.ideafolks.codelist.restful.SectorService.getAllSector(SectorService.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
```

### persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.ideafolks.codelist.datastore.tables.Sector</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
        <property name="datanucleus.singletonEMFForName" value="true" /> <!-- 
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" />  -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

EMF.java

```
public final class EMF {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private EMF() {
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
        return emfInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably added persistence-api-1.0.jar to your classpath. geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar has newer version of JPA API (LockModeType has PESSIMISTIC_READ field), so you can just remove persistence-api-1.0.jar and everything will work fine. Your app worked locally because you might have GAE container higher on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

i've had this error before, and it happened on gae instead of eclipse as well ...
it happens when you try to read from a table before you have any data in the table. try inserting a record first .. perhaps create an initialization servlet. i dont think there is anything wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

The error simply is that the member field PESSIMISTIC_READ is not found in the jar geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0. I have tried all the version of this jar. It simply doesn't find this member. So what I did is just add this enum to the project

package javax.persistence;

public enum LockModeType {
    READ,
    WRITE,
    OPTIMISTIC,
    OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT,
    PESSIMISTIC_READ,
    PESSIMISTIC_WRITE,
    PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT,
    NONE
}

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to remove persistence-api-1.0.jar from the war/WEB-INF/lib too.